# run crontab as root?, trying to run cmd with root access. help

Tags: unix, cron

I have an cpp program that run ok in the command line (as root) but do not run good from crontab. I think it may be because the crontab run not as root.

I have tried:

```
1. crontab -eu root
* * * * * /usr/bin/convertPremium.o
2. crontab -eu root
* * * * * root /usr/bin/convertPremium.o
3. crontab -e
* * * * * root /usr/bin/convertPremium.o
4. crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/bin/convertPremium.o
5. crontab -e
* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/convertPremium.o
```

But nothing works for me.
Sections 2,3 and 5 doent even run the program at all.

1 and 4 runs the program but doest make some of the cmds, i think becouse it not root running it

using UNIX. Hoping for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, i fix my problem by output my crontab execute to log file. 
by that i saw that when running the row ffmpeg -i ... that ffmpeg was unknown because of the path.

Answer (score 2):

1. Premium.o appears to be an object file.  You cannot execute an object file.
2. Assuming #1 is the wrong take on this, that you use a bizarre naming convention instead,
   you have to specify everything that is set in the root user's environment in the one line of the crontab entry:

   - - - - - . /etc/profile && /path/to/Premium.o

This is just a guess at what you need to specify.

Plus you do realize that cron entry (when you get it working) is going to run every minute of every day?  You can use the at command, which is far friendlier, and have it run once at a specified time.  Otherwise you need to read up